# ASP.NET SignalR momentarily loses communication and user is disconnected and connected again

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr, delayed-execution

Is there any possibility to keep alive connection when user go to other subpage?

I have @Url.Action("Action","Controller")

And Jquery click function attached to Url.Action which execute signalR hub server method.
And here I'm stuck because when Url.Action is executing then user is disconnected for a while and signalR method don't work because don't have user connected.

Maybe I can delay this JQuery function for 3s?

Answer (score 0):

Use [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) to prevent page reload.
And check ["push state"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) if you want to maintain #-free urls.